# Using CompletableFuture.allOf on a variable number of objects

Tags: java, spring, completable-future

Please bear with me, i dont usually use spring and havent used newer versions of java (I say newer I mean anything past prob 1.4)

Anyway, I have an issue where I have to do rest calls to do a search using multiple parallel requests. Ive been looking around online and I see you can use CompletableFuture.

So I created my method to get the objects I need form the rest call like:

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<QueryObject[]> queryObjects(String url)
{
    QueryObject[] objects= restTemplate.getForObject(url, QueryObject[].class);
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(objects);
}
```

Now I need to call that with something like:

```
CompletableFuture<QueryObject> page1 = QueryController.queryObjects("http://myrest.com/ids=[abc, def, ghi]);
CompletableFuture<QueryObject> page2 = QueryController.queryObjects("http://myrest.com/ids=[jkl, mno, pqr]);
```

The problem I have is that the call needs to only do three ids at a time and there could be a list of variable number ids. So I parse the idlist and create a query string like above. The problem with that I am having is that while I can call the queries I dont have separate objects that I can then call CompletableFuture.allOf on.

Can anyone tell me the way to do this? Ive been at it for a while now and Im not getting any further than where I am now.
Happy to provide more info if the above isnt sufficient

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting any benefit of using the `CompletableFuture` in a way you're using it right now.

The `restTemplate` method you're using is a synchronous method, so it has to finish and return a result, before proceeding. Because of that wrapping the final result in a `CompletableFuture` doesn't cause it to be executed asynchronously (neither in parallel). You just wrap a response, that you have already retrieved.

If you want to benefit from the async execution, then you can use for example the [AsyncRestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/AsyncRestTemplate.html) or the [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html) .

A simplified code example:

```
public ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<QueryObject[]>> queryForObjects(String url) {
    return asyncRestTemplate.getForEntity(url, QueryObject[].class);
}

public List<QueryObject> queryForList(String[] elements) {
    return Arrays.stream(elements)
        .map(element -> queryForObjects("http://myrest.com/ids=[" + element + "]"))
        .map(future -> future.completable().join())
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .map(HttpEntity::getBody)
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```